# How to get the actual type of a template typed class member with Clang?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, libtooling

For example, I have the following class:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    T getBar();

private:
    T bar_;
};
```

It is instantiated as:

```
Foo<Bar> foo;
```

I extract the `clang::CXXRecordDecl` node of `class Foo`, and iterate through its fields:

```
for (const clang::FieldDecl *fieldDecl: fooRecordDecl->fields()) {
    // fieldDecl->getType() gives T
    // fieldDecl->getNameAsString() gives bar_
}
```

I want something that does `fieldDecl->getInstantiatedType()` that gives `Bar`

I understand that the AST for the `CXXRecordDecl` of `Foo` shouldn't contain any information on the instantiated type. **I was wondering if this linking information was stored somewhere else in the AST, and how I could retrieve it.**

---

My current solution involves getting uninitialized template parameters in order, say `{A, B, C}` for `template<typename A, typename B, typename C> class Baz {};` and storing them in an `std::vector`. Then finding the instantiation call `Baz<Foo, Bar, Baz>`, and store the instantiated types in order in another `std::vector`, and link them together by index to get:

```
{ A: Foo, B: Bar, C: Baz}
```

This seems very convoluted and "un-Clang" like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an "un-Clang" way indeed. Clang usually stores all instantiations separately and it is important to get to the right class declaration. In your case, I guess you took a wrong turn somewhere in the "I extract `clang::CXXRecordDecl`..." part.

I put a small visitor solution, it is a bit campy, but it's easy to adapt it for your needs:

```cpp
bool VisitVarDecl(VarDecl *VD) {
  // VD->getType() dump would look like smth like this:
  //
  // > TemplateSpecializationType 0x7ffbed018180 'Foo<class Bar>' sugar Foo
  // > |-TemplateArgument type 'class Bar'
  // > `-RecordType 0x7ffbed018160 'class Foo<class Bar>'
  // >   `-ClassTemplateSpecialization 0x7ffbed018078 'Foo'
  //
  // The following code unwraps types to get to that ClassTemplateSpecialization
  auto SpecializationDecl = VD->getType()
                                ->getAs<TemplateSpecializationType>()
                                ->desugar()
                                ->getAs<RecordType>()
                                ->getDecl();

  // these fields will have specialized types
  for (const auto *Field : SpecializationDecl->fields()) {
    Field->getType().dump();
  }

  return true;
}
```

For the following snippet:

```cpp
// test.cpp
class Bar {};

template <typename T> class Foo {
public:
  T getBar();

private:
  T bar_;
};

int main() { Foo<Bar> foo; }
```

it produces this ouput:

```
SubstTemplateTypeParmType 0x7ffbed0183b0 'class Bar' sugar
|-TemplateTypeParmType 0x7ffbed017900 'T' dependent depth 0 index 0
| `-TemplateTypeParm 0x7ffbed017890 'T'
`-RecordType 0x7ffbed017750 'class Bar'
  `-CXXRecord 0x7ffbed0176b0 'Bar'
```

As you can see, it has a sugared version of `T` that contains a reference to `Bar`.

I hope this is what you are looking for. Happy hacking with Clang!

Answer (score 0):

For each instantiation of a class template there will be a ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl under the ClassTemplateDecl node in the AST. Commonly the CXXRecordDecl you visited in the question will be the first node under ClassTemplateDecl, then those ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl(s) which is a subclass of CXXRecordDecl. The information you need are in those ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl(s).

But RecursiveASTVisitor doesn't visit these ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl(s) by default. If you need to visit them, you need to:

```
class MyVisitor: public RecursiveASTVisitor<MyVisitor> {
...
bool shouldVisitTemplateInstantiations() const { return true;}
...
}
```

then for each elements in the template like field/member function, the related Visit*** function will be called once for the template element (i.e. in the question) and once for each instantiation of it.